# React-Native-Image not playing full gif

Tags: ios, react-native, gif

I have a gif here:

[image: nsgif-15018727507]

And I have my `index.ios.js` here:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 200, height: 400}}
          source={{uri: this.state.path}} />
      </View>
```

However this is what the output is:

[image: giphy]

Any ideas on how to make it play the whole gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, fresh new project with React Native `0.47.1`.

The render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={{width: 200, height: 400}} 
               source={{uri: 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13806068/28982817-ffd1fdc2-790b-11e7-9bc2-a2d1135ca232.gif'}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output gif opens up Safari instead of an iOS application. Could you post output gif when trying to open the app?

Also you might want to confirm value of `this.state.path` which you are using as source of the `gif`.

It needs to have the extension `.gif` in it to work. For e.g

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://www.urltogif/image.gif'}} /> 

//or

<Image source={require('./path/to/image/local.gif')} />
```

You can find a working example here https://snack.expo.io/ByglJIzD-

Comment: This is the gif. The safari opening is part of the gif :) This is the original gif path: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13806068/28982817-ffd1fdc2-790b-11e7-9bc2-a2d1135ca232.gif

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/BkIPe8Mvb updated the example, it loads and runs the entire gif

Comment: That does work... I wonder why it is not working for me, I am going to play around with it some more in my own project. Thank for the help!

Comment: i figured it out! I *think* that the reason it had an issue is because I would re-set the state in a function that was run in render, so every time it re-set the state it would re-load the image

Comment: Ok, you shouldn't reset state in render methods. probably use eventHandlers(onPress etc.) or componentWillReceiveProps for whatever state mutations you would want to do :)

Comment: Try to avoid of using `componentWillReceiveProps`, it can lead to limbo and weird cases

Comment: If used properly it shouldn't lead to any weird cases in my opinion. Many times this point is missed when dealing with `componentWillReceiveProps` https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html